# In DFP, is it possible to use creative of one size on ad-units with different sizes?

Tags: advertising, google-dfp, ad-server

I'm using a custom create type on DFP SMB, since the text has to be in Hebrew, the original text ad type doesn't work well.

I made some text ads with width of the content (440x30) and they work well on most part.
The problem is with mobile, since the text ads are too wide, it doesn't fit info the screen width.

I already know about [DFP responsive ads feature](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=en), and understand how to use it, but the problem will be to duplicate each creative for each of the sizes we use. That's something we can't do right now (too time consuming).

Is it possible to use a custom creative type of one size to be shown on multiple ad-units sizes?

for example: creative with size 440x30 to be used on 440x30 units on desktop, but 320x50 on mobiles

Comment: If you find this answer helpful to you, please [accept this answer as
correct](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFP has an option for "Allow creative size to differ from ad unit size". Here is the [help page that describes how to use it](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/82276)

> With DFP Small Business, you can target smaller creatives to a larger ad unit (example: a 120x600 creative in a 160x600 ad unit) without the ad displaying extra white space. You can also target larger creatives to smaller ad units, but must select **Allow creative size to differ from ad unit size** if using an image or Flash creative.